# How to get image from firebase storage having the url React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Here is my code the problem is that it is getting the state of imgAddress when it's still nothing => "" and the state is never being changed I'm not getting the new state of imgAddress in the `<p></p>` tag neither Help me please the problem is the async-ity but I can't solve it

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import * as fb from 'firebase';

export default function Page() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
    const [img, setImg] = useState("");
    const [imgAddress, setImgAddress] = useState("");


    useEffect(() => {   //useEffect որտև անվերջ անում ա stackoverflow-ում հարցրել էի մի անգամ
        fb.database().ref('users/' + fb.auth().currentUser.uid).on('value', (e) => {
            let db = e.val();
            console.log(db);
            setAge(db.age);
            setUsername(db.username);
            setImg(db.img);
            setEmail(db.email);
        });
        fb.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
            if (img != "") {
                console.log('mtav user');
                fb.storage().ref(`avatars/${fb.auth().currentUser.uid}/${img}`).getDownloadURL().then(e => {
                    console.log('LALALALALALALALA')
                    console.log(e);
                    setImgAddress(e);
                })
                    .catch(e => console.log(e))
            }
            else {
                console.log("chmtav");
            }
        })

    }, []);


    return (
        <>
            <h1>Hello</h1>

            <ul>
                <li>Email: {email}</li>
                <li>Username: {username}</li>
                <li>Image name: {img}</li>
                <li>Age: {age}</li>
                <a href={imgAddress} alt="avatar">Image</a>
                <p>{imgAddress}</p>
            </ul>

        </>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image: The appearance]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out finally, I just moved the getting code out from the useEffect and now it works, but I don't understand why if anyone could explain me I would mark is answer as a correct one, btw Now it consoles it 4-5 times randomly